# Referencing Namespaces in C# headers with using-directives

Tags: c#, .net, namespaces, using-directives

I want to have using codes like as shown below, for example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
```

but this c# code below (taken from the question [Command prompt output being read as empty string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11060019/command-prompt-output-being-read-as-empty-string)) has no headers like above to compiled with csc.exe in cmd console and i tried to comment on that thread but a requirement of 50 reputation is needed and i had no VB studio IDE yet and im new to learning C#.

```
var output = new StringBuilder();
var error = new StringBuilder();

cmd.OutputDataReceived += (o, e) => output.Append(e.Data);
cmd.ErrorDataReceived += (o, e) => error.Append(e.Data);

cmd.Start();
cmd.BeginOutputReadLine();
cmd.BeginErrorReadLine();
cmd.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: Welcome on SO! Any other complaints that you want to share? We all went through that stage so it is not necessary to explain that to us. You will get features unlocked quickly if you participate in the site. Start right now and make your question a good, useful one that fits the Q&A format well.

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow! To avoid the downvotes and help build some rep, you should really structure your questions as a question. In this case it could be as simple as adding your compiler errors, and asking which namespaces should be added.

Comment: Also if you are new to C#, having the VisualStudio IDE really helps, since it gives you intellisense and errors right in your code. You can actually download VisualStudio Express for free. http://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs#d-express-windows-desktop

Answer (score 1):

Process belongs to System.Diagnostics, and StringBuilder belongs to System.Text.

If in doubt, google the method names and see what objects have them on MSDN, then look at their namespace.

Comment: i compiled it but got an errors xxx.cs(1,1): error CS0116: A namespace cannot directly contain members such as f
ields or methods
xxx.cs(4,18): error CS1518: Expected class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct

xxx.cs(5,17): error CS1518: Expected class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct

Press any key to continue . . .

Comment: Edited my answer to correct namespace for StringBuilder.

Comment: @Dodzkie You can't just put that code into a .cs file and compile. It needs to be inside a method, which needs to be inside a class.

Comment: @adam you're right as it does not solved in .cs file to be compiled with csc.exe in cmd console as its the same error again when i put these two in first two lines:  using System.Diagnostics;
     using System.Text;